# Ошибка при выполнении switch или equals cо строковым типом Java

Tags: java, java-ee

Передаю get-запросом данные из формы в сервлет и присваиваю полученные данные переменной. После чего хочу произвести сравнения для выполнения нужного хода событий, но при запуске сервера получаю ошибку:

> Type Exception Report
>
> Description The server encountered an unexpected condition that
>   prevented it from fulfilling the request.
>
> Exception
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException
>     mymvn.myservlet.doGet(myservlet.java:49)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:635)
>     javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
>     org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
>   Note The full stack trace of the root cause is available in the server
>   logs.

IDE вроде как настроил на нужную версию JDK:

> To change the project bytecode version in IntelliJ IDEA:
>
> Open File > Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java
>   Compiler
>
> Set the Project bytecode version to 1.8

Но всё равно ошибка. Вот мой код с **switch**:

```
String datestart = request.getParameter("datestart");

String Shift = request.getParameter("shift");

switch (Shift)
{
    case "1":
        datestart = datestart + " 22:00";
        break;
    case "2":
        break;
    case "3":
        break;
    case "null":
        System.out.println("Null test");
        break;
}
```

и с **if:**

```
if (Shift.equals("1"))
{
 datestart = datestart + " 22:00";
}
```

Ошибка одна и та же, помогите пожалуйста разобраться что я делаю не так ? Спасибо.

Comment: Нужен _the full stack trace of the root cause_ для точного ответа, но скорее всего `request.getParameter("shift")` вернул `null`.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev да по дефолту shift возвращает `null` как исправить ? сделать проверку перед выполнением ? `if (Shift != null) {}` ? Или как-то иначе  ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
String shift = request.getParameter("shift");

if (shift != null) {
    switch (shift) {
        case "1":
            datestart = datestart + " 22:00";
            break;
        case "2":
            break;
        case "3":
            break;
        case default:
            System.out.println("Invalid value");
            break;
    }
}
else {
    System.out.println("Null test");
}
```

И, если значение `shift` всегда число, то лучше преобразовать его в `int`.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Преобразование в Java так : `Integer.parseInt(Shift);` ?

Comment: Да, именно так.

Comment: Большое спасибо вам за помощь.